# How to monitor a Windows process' working set greater than 4GB?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, powershell, performance-monitoring

Apparently the .NET framework has a bug that prevents working set values above 2GB from accurately being determined. Between 2 and 4GB one can apply some xor-ing calculation to obtain the value, but there's no means of obtaining working set values greater than 4GB (using .Net or WMI)

What method can be used - preferably from a PowerShell script - to obtain an accurate measurement of a process' working set when the working set is greater than 4GB?

(some side details can be found in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417944/converting-large-integers-into-meaningful-values-via-bitwise-operations))

Comment: So WMI has the same issue? (Would imply that .NET is using WMI and the defect is in WMI.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for monitoring a specific process:

```
"\Process(<process name>)\Working Set" | get-counter -computer <computer>
```

The output is in bytes, but you can convert it to GB in the following command:

```
"\Process(<process name>)\Working Set" | get-counter -computer <computer>
| ForEach {$_.CounterSamples} | ForEach {[math]::round($_.cookedvalue/1GB,2)}
```

**Edit:**
Reading the SO post, I see you are trying to just get any processes over 4 GB, without passing a specific process to the script.  Below is a script that will do this, and here is a link to a [Scripting Guy blog article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/02/16/hey-scripting-guy-february-16-2010a.aspx) that explains how to use the `Get-Counter` cmdlet:

```
"\Process(*)\Working Set" | Get-Counter -computer <computer>
| ForEach {$_.CounterSamples} | ? {$_.cookedvalue -gt 4294967296} | ft -AutoSize
```

Comment: Outstanding. So simple. Thank you for clearing the forest of the trees. Like other performance counters, Passing a * as the process name returns the working set for all processes. Thanks again, August.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question but still alive,
this show real 64bit memory usage in powershell:

get-process $Processname -computername $Computername | ft Name,ID,VirtualMemorySize64,PeakVirtualMemorySize64,WorkingSet64,PeakWorkingSet64

and this show memory usage over 
gps |where {$_.workingset64 -gt 4000Mb }|ft name,pm,workingset64,id